# How do I find the position (coordinates) of my rect?

Tags: python, pygame

```
player_stand = pygame.image.load('graphics/player/player_stand.png').convert_alpha()
player_stand = pygame.transform.scale(player_stand,(136, 168))
player_stand_rect = player_stand.get_rect(center = (400,200))
```

How can I get the exact coordinates of the `player_stand_rect`? It moves around.

Comment: `player_stand_rect.centerx`, `player_stand_rect.centery`?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by "get the exact coordinates" here. Are you using this image and `Rect` with a `Sprite`? Or are you manually setting the coordinates of the rect as it moves? In either case, the same ways you set the coordinates can probably be used to read the coordinates back.

Comment: So you can get the actual _x_ coordinate with `player_stand_rect.centerx` and the actual _y_ coordinate with `player_stand_rect.centery`. Also see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object has a set of virtual attributes that can be read and written to. The center's current x-coordinate can be determined with `player_stand_rect.centerx` and the center's current y-coordinate with `player_stand_rect.centery`. A tuple with the center of the rectangle can be determined via the attribute 'center':

```py
x, y = player_stand_rect.center
```